# Consuming a web service in Microsoft Access

Tags: php, web-services, ms-access

So I am not sure if this is the right website to ask a question like this but so be it ;-)

I have a client who uses Microsoft Access as a front end for MySQL. Now he wants to access some data from a IBM DB2 database and he told me to write a script to import that data into MySQL but I would rather write a PHP Web Service for it because the underlying DB2 database might change.

But I have no clue how to write a web service and make it accessible to Microsoft Access. And is there an option in Microsoft Access to import/use such web service?

I know that using MS-Access as frontend might not always be the best solution, but thats what he has and thats what he is familiar with.

(I know I haven't provided any source code yet, but thats why I am not sure where to ask on this specific task)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140260(v=office.10).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819156%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to go here:

1. Do as requested and just export from DB2 and Import to MySql.
2. Forget about the MYSql server and define ODBC connection to the DB2 server on the users machine and get MSAccess to access the tables directly.

If you had SQLServer or Oracle you could define the DB2 server and tables as remote tables which looked local to the user but I think MySql can only define other MySql tables in this way.

You could try accessing your web server via VBA:

```
Function FirePost(strPage As String, strPost As String)

Dim req As Object 'New MSXML2.XMLHTTP30
Set req = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

req.Open "POST", strPage, False
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
req.Send strPost

FirePost = req.responseText
```

End Function

Code stolen from [here](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=203572)

Comment: thank you for your answer. the db2 already has an odbc connection set up, its just "my client" is not supposed to use the db2 directly. it has to be either through an export and then use the mysql database or through a web service

Comment: @Petros Mastrantonas -- I see your problem. I have added an untested example of how you could access an HTTP page via VBA.